# Uber-Slow wifi connection on Ubuntu 11.10 on my 1310-us

Tags: 11.10, hp

On Ubuntu, my internet speeds (which would normally be good) is very crappy and I can't find help anywhere. Please help! I have an HP Pavilion g7 1310-us and the type of wireless receiver I have is a Broadcom 802.11 a/b/g/n.

Answer (score 0):

got this thing solved for me (well, I didn't myself, got the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1955749)) in a terminal, write:

> echo "options iwlagn 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf
>   sudo modprobe -rfv iwlagn
>   sudo modprobe iwlagn

hope this helps.

#### Edit

try the following commands

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo rmmod -f iwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Try browsing again and if there is an improvement, make this change permanent by
loading this kernel module at boot with the 11n_disable option enabled. This would be done by modifying your /etc/modules file by the following:

```
echo "iwlagn 11_ndisable=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

If that does not work then-

create an 'options' file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options.conf
```

and add the line

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: When I put the first line in I got:" tee: etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn.conf: No such file or directory"

Comment: edited my ans. see if it works for you

Comment: Anyway I added "wl" in /etc/initram-fs/modules and executed update-initramfs -u. Seems that fixed the issue

Comment: so my soln didnt work for you?